# Extract 'href' from elements using Selenium

Tags: python, xpath, selenium

This is my current XPath:

```
//table//tr/td/div/div[1]/div/a/@href
```

It matches ten urls on a page I am looking at. It has ten matches in this form `jobs/720800-Associate-Partner-Investment-Consulting-Vancouver-Job-ID-39708.aspx`

I am trying to using `selenium.get_text()` to pull the `@href` string; however, my calls are pulling blanks (note: not failing, just pulling blanks). I am successfully able to pull strings on other elements on the same page.

I have searched and couldn't find any solution to my problem - does anyone have some advice?

Comment: Some more example input is required.... for instance - what does `//table//tr/td/div/div[1]/div/a[@href]/@href` produce ?

Comment: do you want the text of a particular link or of all links?

Comment: xpather tells me this is a legitimate xpath; however, when I run my script, get_text pulls empty strings and get_attribute gives me an invalid xpath error.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for the text of all links.

Answer (score 2):

this might be a bit late, if you are using python selenium
(based on your tags) you can do it this way (as v2.44.0)
:

```
from selenium import webdriver
# set the driver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
# get the element
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//table//tr/td/div/div[1]/div/a')
# get the attribute value
link = elem.get_attribute('href')
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, the problem is that for that path there are `<a href="XXX">` for which `href` is empty and other anchors for which `href` is not empty. You just want to get those `href` which are not empty. So then, use this expression:

```
//table//tr/td/div/div[1]/div/a[@href!=""]/@href
```

Comment: Thanks. They are all pulling empty but I know they aren't based on looking at the source- I'm just accessing them the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

just Refer to the Anchor tags and don't refer to href attributes. Once we have all elements then perform Get_Attribute() for href element....

```
find_elements_by_xpath("//table//tr/td/div/div[1]/div/a[@href]")
For Loop
print Each_element.Get_Attribute("href")
```

I hope this helps...

Comment: This gives me the text of the /a element but not the text of the href object (i.e., the url string). Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Sorry mate for trouble...Check my updated answer ....this will work... After retrieving elements...instead of GetText() we need to do Get_Attribute() on each element for the url string.

Comment: I tried a for loop using find_elements_by_xpath, find_element_by_xpath and combinations of these methods with "driver." or "browser." before them. I keep getting the 'name: find_element not defined' error or driver or browser not defined. My for loop is taking this form: for i in find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='event-listings']/ul/li/p/a[@href]"):
    print i.get_attribute("href")

Comment: It is possible I need to import an extension besides simply selenium?

Comment: I was finally able to do this using get_attribute. My error was in not including "xpath" in referencing the xpath. Here's the specific command: element1 = sel.get_attribute("xpath=//div[@id='event-listings']/ul/li[2]/p/a@href") . I would like to have it pick up all xpaths that match a specific xpath but I can work with this.

Comment: Yeah...as mentioned it picks href of first Xpath matching element... May be you can write your own Function Own_Class.Get_Href_Attributes() where it first find all elements matching xpath and then it get Href attributes of all such elements in list (returnable)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
get_attribute("//table//tr/td/div/div[1]/div/a@href");
```

Comment: Thanks Santoshsarma. Unfortunately I'm getting an invalud xpath error when I run this: Invalid xpath [2]: (//div[@id='event-listings']/ul/li/p/a where the "@href: followed the ".../p/a"

Comment: Try like this : //div[@id='event-listings']/ul/li/p/a@href